# How do I include images into Outlook 2007 MailItem using perl?

Tags: perl, outlook

I have this code and a bunch of images in a folder.

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';

%mail_props = ('subject' => 'subject','to' => 'to','body' => 'body',);

my $outlook = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application');
# Create Mail Item
my $item = $outlook->CreateItem(0);  # 0 = mail item.
unless ($item){die "Outlook is not running, cannot send mail.\n";}

$item->{'Subject'} = $mail_props{'subject'} || '[No Subject]';
$item->{'To'} = join(";", split(/[ ,;]+/, $mail_props{'to'}));
$item->{'Body'} = $mail_props{'body'} || "\r\n";
$item->{'From'} = $mail_props{'from'} if (exists $mail_props{'from'});

$item->Display();

print "Done!\n";
```

Does anyone know a way to add images to the body of the email generated using above code using OLE methods? I am working with Outlook 2007 and need a code equivalent for inserting tables and pictures.

Appreciate all your help...

Answer (score 0):

Are the tables separate objects or just inlined HTML?  Lookout (sorry Outlook) can actually handle inlined uuencode'd objects within the body: basically just insert the uuencoded image in the body and Outlook will parse and show as an attachment.  If the OLE doesn't allow for setting MIME boundaries in the mail message, you might try the [uuencode](http://search.cpan.org/~andk/Convert-UU-0.5201/lib/Convert/UU.pm) approach.

Comment: what do you mean by inlined HTML?

Comment: Just that you can have HTML as the email body.